# Overwriting /boot/grub/menu.lst?

Tags: linux, sed

Before overwriting I have copied /boot/grub/menu.lst to /home/san. I am running sed on the /home/san/menu.lst just for testing.

How can i overwrite

> default        0

to

> default        1

with the help of sed. I used following commands but none worked. It's most probably because i don't how many spaces are there in between "default" and "0". I thought there were two spaces and one tab but I was wrong.

```
sed -e 's/default  \t0/default  \t1/' /home/san/menu.lst
sed -e 's/default\t0/default\t1/' /home/san/menu.lst
sed -e 's/default \t0/default \t1/' /home/san/menu.lst
sed -e 's/default  0/default 1/' /home/san/menu.lst
```

I actually want to write a script that may see if 'default 0' is written in menu.lst then replace it with 'default 1' and if 'default 1' is written then replace it with 'default 2'.

Thanks

**Update:**

How can used a conditional statement to see if the line starting with 'default' has "0" or "1" written after it? If "0" replace with "1" and if "1" replace it with "0"?

Comment: You should really post your update as a **separate** question. (And perhaps explain the use case, as it does not seem to describe something you'd find in `menu.lst`...?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (with another file, of course ;)

```
sed -re 's/^default([ \t]+)0$/default\11/' /home/san/menu.lst
```

**How it works:**

1. Passing `-r` to [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) allows us to use extended regular expressions, thus no need to escape the parentheses and plus sign.
2. `[ \t]+` matches one or more tabs or spaces, in any order.
3. Putting parentheses around this, that is `([ \t]+)`, turns this into a *group*, to which we can refer.
4. This is the only group in this case, thus `\1`. That is what happens in the replacement string.
5. We don't want to replace `default 0` as part of a larger string. Thus we use `^` and `$`, which match the start and end of the line, respectively.

**Note that:**

1. Using a group is not strictly necessary. You can also opt to replace all those tabs and spaces by a single tab or space. In that case just omit the parentheses and replace `\1` with a space:

   ```
   sed -re 's/^default[ \t]+0$/default 1/' /home/san/menu.lst
   ```
2. This will fail if there is trailing whitespace after `default 0`. If that is a concern, then you can match `[ \t]*` (zero or more tabs and spaces) just before the EOL:

   ```
   sed -re 's/^default([ \t]+)0[ \t]*$/default\11/' /home/san/menu.lst
   ```

Comment: Thanks man. :) Can you please tell what does 'default\11' mean?

Comment: Awesome. Loved the 'group' thing.
Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks for the note. Can you please see the post again. I have updated it with a new but related question when you get some free time?

Comment: You should really post that as a **separate** question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could use several lines like this:

```
 sed -re 's/default([ \t]*)0/default\11/' /home/san/menu.lst.
```

However, you might be better off with one line like this:

```
 awk '/^default/ { if ($2 == 1) print "default  0" ; else print "default 1" } !/^default/ {print}' /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Comment: Thanks Shannon. Is there a way with awk to see if its "1" in front of "default", then replace it with "0" or if its "0" then replace with "1". Or should i use IF-ELSE statement.

Comment: Thanks Shannon for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

This substitutes 1 for 0, 0 for 1:

```
sed -r '/^default[ \t]+[01]$/{s/0/1/;t;s/1/0/}'
```

This substitutes 1 for 0, 2 for 1, 0 for 2:

```
sed -r '/^default[ \t]+[012]$/{s/0/1/;t;s/1/2/;t;s/2/0/}'
```

Briefly:

- `/^default[ \t]+[01]$/` uses addressing to select lines that consist only of "default 0" or "default 1" (or "default 2" in the second form) with any non-zero amount of spaces and/or tabs between "default" and the number
- `s/0/1/` - substitute a "1" for a "0"
- `t` - branch to the end if a substitution was made, if not then continue with the next command
- followed by more substitution(s) (and branches)

**Edit**:

Here's another way to do it:

```
sed -r '/^default[ \t]+[012]$/y/012/120/'
```